# Differentiating between two users on the same client machine in C#

Tags: c#, networking, remote-desktop

I was wondering if there is a way of differentiating between two users on the same Windows Server client machine?

We have some Windows Server machines that are setup to allow concurrent users. These two concurrent users can then both simultaneously have remote desktops open (via Microsoft RDC). However, the only way I have found to identify which client machine is the variable %CLIENTNAME%. Both of the concurrent users would return the same client name variable since they are using different sessions of the same Windows Server machine.

Is there any other variable or way to differentiate both users if they are using the same machine?

Comment: Surely these users are logged in under different accounts.

Comment: In that case `Environment.UserName` would be the obvious choice. The same class would be the preferred way to get the machine name from managed code too.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, they are logged in under different accounts. But how can you retrieve that user name from the host machine? Or anything other variable on the host machine to tell me more about who is logged in

Comment: What has the host machine got to do with anything? Are they logged into the server under different accounts or not?

Comment: @jmcilhinney The Host Machine only knows the name of the Client Machine. It does not specify the user logged in to the Client Machine.

So if Client Machine X has two active users (each with separate credentials), and they both log in to different machines, A and B. Machines A and B will have the variable ClientName = "X". What I am trying to see is if there are any other variables that Host Machines A and B have to identify the users of Client Machine X. Credentials are not an option as they might use different credentials for a particular host machine.

Answer (score 0):

You want the equivalent of SESSIONNAME   on a remote session it will often look like  RDP-Tcp#0     and RDP-Tcp#1    there will also be a session called console that will be the local non remote session.

Run this at the command prompt of a remote session on your server.

echo %COMPUTERNAME% %USERDOMAIN% %USERNAME% %SESSIONNAME% logged in from %CLIENTNAME%

That will give you an idea.

CLIENTNAME will not be defined in the local session so any code you write will have to protect against that.

I Would NOT use Clientname because a person could start and end a session from a different client or desktop PC.

Comment: Thanks. Will the Client Machine have this information as well so I can then just pair up the RDP-TCP#0 on the Remote Session to the variable on the local machine?

Comment: Only the server sessions where the remote clients are logged into will will have the unique names in SESSIONNAME.   Try running this at a command promt while logged into a remote desktop session to see the effect...   c:\>    echo %COMPUTERNAME% %USERDOMAIN% %USERNAME% %SESSIONNAME%